# Petroncini roaster issue

Tags: roasting, roast

I have a petroncini raoster, semi-automatic
It's really good, but I whenever I fase an issue, I find really hard to understand -and fix- it.
I have been searching for a while now, for an operation manual or any form of help, but I could find nothing.
Does any one have any idea where can I find a petroncini user manual or operation manual or any sort of operation documentation ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The only thing I can suggest at the moment is to contact Petroncini direct and see if they can help, it looks like they have a worldwide service facility so I see no harm in asking for a user manual.